# VB6 - Run Time Error 48

Tags: vb6, runtime-error

I got this error in some VB6 applications after I had uninstalled another VB6 application and I fixed it by reinstalling the applicaton so that the dll was reinstalled.

However I still do not know which dll was the problem. If I can find out its name I can put it in the install script for the other applications so thay are always OK.

Question - How can I find out the name of the dll that was removed and caused error message 48?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Try watching the process as it loads using Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).  You will see it probing for each dll.

Comment: Or equivalently the Profile option in Depends.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have access to the source code?

If that is the case, you can use the Regsvr32 tool to manually register and deregister dll's in order to find out which ones are required to run your application:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873/en-us

Comment: I don't think Error 48 normally occurs for ActiveX DLLs, only for standard DLLs (e.g. used via `Declare Function` statements).

Comment: Yep, I guess you are right. With my ActiveX DLL I get an Automation Error 8007007e after renaming the file. This link here specifically talks about libraries in a DECLARE statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232611(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Hi Luke Wage,I do have access to the source code. What should I do?

Comment: Well in that case run the application in debug mode. As soon as it tries to call the missing DLL, it will stop and you will see the function name. Have a look at your [Declare Function] statements. There you will see the function name again along with the name of the missing dll.